# listing the contents of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to write a function: CANNOT CHANGE THE FUNCTION! 
`void list_courses() that lists all the course numbers enrolled by all the students in order. how do i approach this problem?

Comment: `head` is undefined in your function, so `head->courses` is an invalid reference. Where is your student list defined? Seems that a pointer to student (the first one in the student list) should be passed as an argumen to your `list_courses`.

Comment: start with `void courses(struct course *c){
    if(c == NULL){
          printf("No courses"); return;
    } while(c){ printf("grade:%c, number:%u\n, c->grade, c->number); c = c->next; } 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say we shouldn't change the function `void list_courses()` but you must have a `struct student *` somewhere to start iterating over all students and all courses. You seem to have that initial student in a static variable, i'm gonna assume you fill that static variable somehow. Here's how i would do it:

```
static struct student *my_student;

void list_courses(){

    struct student *current_student = my_student;
    struct course *current_course;

    // Iterate over all students
    while(current_student != NULL){
        current_course = current_student->courses;

        // do something with the current student if needed ...

        // Iterate over courses of this student
        while(current_course != NULL){

            // do something with current course ...

            // Advance to the next course of this student
            current_course = current_course->next;
        }

        // Advance to the next student
        current_student = current_student->next;
    }
}
```

This code could be more compact, but i did a verbose version for clarity sake.